# Show that the kernel of $\lambda$ is the set of all polynomials $p\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ that are divisible by $x^2+1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ denote the field $$\mathbb{F}=\{r+si: r,s\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
(Here $i$ is the infamous element of $\mathbb{C}$ with $i^2=-1$.) Consider the function $\lambda: \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{F}$ defined by $$\lambda(p)=p(i) \qquad \text{ for all } p\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$$

1) Show that $\lambda$ is a ring homomorphism.

Proof of (1):
Let $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then we need to show that $\lambda(f+g)=\lambda(f)+\lambda(g)$. So 
$$\lambda(f+g)=(f+g)(i)=f(i)+g(i)=\lambda(f)+\lambda(g) $$

Let $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then we need to show that $\lambda(fg)=\lambda(f)\lambda(g)$. So 
$$\lambda(fg)=(fg)(i)=f(i)g(i)=\lambda(f)\lambda(g) $$

Let $f=1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then we need to show that $\lambda(1)=1$. So
$\lambda(1)=1(i)=1$.

Hence $\lambda$ is a ring homomorphism.

2) Show that the kernel of $\lambda$ is the set of all polynomials $p\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ that are divisible by $x^2+1$.

How would I do part 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Suppose $x^{2} + 1 \mid p(x)$. Then $p(x) = (x^{2}+1)g(x)$ for some $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Now use part (1) to show $p(x) \in \ker(\lambda)$.

Suppose $p(x) \in \ker(\lambda)$. Use Euclidean division over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ to divide $p(x)$ by $x^{2}+1$. We obtain $p(x) = q(x)(x^{2}+1)+r(x)$ for some $r(x)$ with degree less than $2$, so $\lambda(p(x)) = \lambda(q(x)(x^{2}+1)+r(x)) = 0$. Now use part (1) again to conclude something about $r(x)$.

Comment: Do you mean suppose $p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ instead of suppose $p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Hmm? Where do I say either?

Comment: Second paragraph. So $\lambda(p(x))=\lambda(q(x))\lambda(x^2+1)+\lambda(r(x))=q(i)(i^2+1)+r(i)=r(i)$. So $r(x)=0$.

Comment: I still don't see where I say suppose $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ or $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$. But yes, exactly. Hence, you've shown an element $p(x)$ is in the kernel if and only if $x^{2}+1 \mid p(x)$

Comment: Haha perfect. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure! :)